# Pass associative array through Ajax

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, django

I've been trying to understand AJAX, and I do manage to send single pieces of data. But when I try to send an array nothing goes trough. I've tried to format it as JSON, but not really been successful in that regard. I've searched trough stackoverflow by any combinations of tips and tricks have almost gotten me all the way.

Here is the JS without most of the math to get the prices:

```
    var data = [];

    $('[id$="-subtotal"]').each(function () {
      subtotal = some_math;          
      id = some_ID_Number;
      data['id-' + String(id)] = subtotal
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: '/test/',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
        'prices': data,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
      },
      success: function (data) {

      }
    });
```

And I've been trying to access the array with:

> request.POST.get('prices')

Comment: You should json data instead of array.  You can not pass array to ajax

Comment: That's not correct, according to the docs (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you can send a PlainObject or Array, that will be converted to a query string by AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are not using `$.each()` correctly. Try this:

   $.each($('[id$="-subtotal"]'), function (key, element) {
     subtotal = some_math;
     id = some_ID_Number;
     data['id-' + String(id)] = subtotal
   });

---

2. You should declare `data` as an object, not an array. An array can only have numeric keys. An object can have keys that contain other characters. If you `console.log(data)` you will see that `data` will contain data if it's an object, and will be empty if initialized as an array. So try this:

```js
  var data = {};

  $.each($('*'), function() {
    subtotal = Math.random() * 100;
    id = Math.random() * 100;
    data['id-' + String(id)] = subtotal
  });

  console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the array gets created properly with the original code, but yours look better. If I simply override the array with `data = [1, 2, 3]` it gets sent trough properly and I can access it. I seem to have problems with an associative array, which is what I've built in the function above the ajax.

Comment: I changed my answer above with a second possible solution.

Comment: That was it, I did have to JSON stringify it first: `JSON.stringify(data)`
then in the view I simply did this: `test_dict = json.loads(request.POST.get('prices'))`